# Translate routing and menu titles

Tags: 8, routes, navigation

I've made two yml files, for both routing and menu item:

Route:

```
tester_helper.products_controller_overview:
  path: '/assortment'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\tester_helper\Controller\ProductsController::overview'
    _title: 'Assortment'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Menu item:

```
tester_helper.products_controller_overview_link:
  title: Assortment
  parent: main
  route_name: tester_helper.products_controller_overview
  menu_name: main
  weight: 3
```

Is it possible to translate both the path and the menu item title?

For example:
EN (english):
"Assortment" => /assortment

DE (german):
"Sortiment" => /sortiment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_title` in `*.routing.yml` and `title` in `*.links.menu.yml` are translatable by default. Go to user translation (/admin/config/regional/translate) and search there for 'Assortment' and translate it.

The path is not translatable. See this similar question:

[Translating paths in routing.yml](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207316/translating-paths-in-routing-yml)

In the answer you find some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try my luck translating the paths with aliases.