# Dynamically creating menu items

Tags: 8, navigation

What I need is to add menu item to some menu, but it should have different parameters (title and url) depending on language. So I created new module and added `links.menu.yml` like:

```
my_menu_item_id:
  title: 'Dummy Title'
  description: 'Dummy Description'
  url: http://www.google.com
  parent: mainmenu
  menu_name: mainmenu
  weight: -100
```

And item appears well. Then I added `menu_links_discovered_alter` hook like:

```
    function mymodule_menu_links_discovered_alter(&$links) {
      $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
      $links['my_menu_item_id']['title'] = 'Title:'.$language;
    }
```

And title really get's altered, but that renaming is cached. So when I visit some page in other language previous title remains until I clear the cache. How to solve this. How to make Drupal execute this code with every page instead of using cached value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discovery process is not the right place for dynamic behavior. A menu link defined statically in a yaml file can provide dynamic values only in a menu link plugin class.

In your case you would implement the method [`MenuLinkInterface::getTitle`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21MenuLinkInterface.php/function/MenuLinkInterface%3A%3AgetTitle/8.6.x):

```
  public function getTitle() {
    return $title;
  }
```

See this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/249342/47547 for a complete example of a menu link class.

Although for translating the title this should not be necessary, titles of routes and menu links are covered by interface translation, see [Translate routing and menu titles](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215486/translate-routing-and-menu-titles)

Comment: Thank you 4k4, getTitle() override you suggested works. But how can I change url of menu item? I don't see any method that I can also override in that class.

Comment: override [MenuLinkInterface::getUrlObject](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21MenuLinkInterface.php/function/MenuLinkInterface%3A%3AgetUrlObject/8.6.x) and `return Url::fromUri('http://www.google.com');`