# Translatable paths with parameters in routing.yml

Tags: 8, routes, i18n-l10n

Given the following `routing.yml`:

```
my_module.my_route:
    path: 'some-path-in-english/{slug}'
    defaults:
         _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyController::__invoke'
    requirements:
         _permission: 'access content'
```

I want to be able to have custom paths by language. For example:

- /some-path-in-english/{slug}
- /es/mi-ruta-en-castellano/{slug}

I checked [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207316/translating-paths-in-routing-yml) answers but generating alias does not solve the problem of parameters in path (at least I could not get it working) and generating a route for each language and controller is not very maintainable an breaks language switcher.

Is there any way to achieve this in Drupal 8?

Comment: That's what path alias is for.

Comment: @IvanJaros How can I make it work with parameters? /some-path-in-english/{slug} -> /es/mi-ruta-en-castellano/{slug} does not seem to work

Comment: That's not how path aliases work. You have pat alias per each unique url. There is no slug. ie. request: /foo-node ---> internal path: /node/5 ---> route: /node/{node}